# Possible useless methods overriding magento2

Tags: magento-2.1, coding-standards, overriding

This is a grid collection file.
In this i didn't get any grid issues.
According to **CodingStandard** it shows this warning:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 32 | WARNING | Possible useless method overriding detected
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The warning shows from this line.

```
$resourceModel = \Companyname\Wallet\Model\ResourceModel\Order::class
```

which I declared **inside the constructor**.

```
<?php
namespace Companyname\Wallet\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid;

use Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\DataProvider\Document;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface as FetchStrategy;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface as EntityFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface as EventManager;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface as Logger;

class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult
{
    public function __construct(
        EntityFactory $entityFactory,
        Logger $logger,
        FetchStrategy $fetchStrategy,
        EventManager $eventManager,
        $mainTable = 'sales_order_grid',
        $resourceModel = \Companyname\Wallet\Model\ResourceModel\Order::class
    ) {
        parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $mainTable, $resourceModel);
    }

    public function _renderFiltersBefore()
    {
        $this->addFieldToFilter('is_wallet_quote', 1);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Anyone facing this issue and anyone knows alternative method for this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you got any answer ?

Comment: I am facing the same warning, have any solution @chris